# cap returns different value for same underlying array

Tags: go, slice

For

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]int, 5)
    printSlice("a", a)

    b := make([]int, 1, 5)
    b[0]=1
    printSlice("b", b)

    c := b[:2]
    printSlice("c", c)

    d := b[2:5]
    printSlice("d", d)
}

func printSlice(s string, x []int) {
    fmt.Printf("%s len=%d cap=%d %v\n",
        s, len(x), cap(x), x)
}
```

The output is

```
a len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0]
b len=0 cap=5 []
c len=2 cap=5 [0 0]
d len=3 cap=3 [0 0 0]
```

Why `c` has `cap=5` while `d` has `cap=3`? As both of them has the same underlying `b` array (which should be `cap=5`)

Comment: Because `d` starts at index `2` of `b` while `c` starts at index `0`, and slices can only grow their end, not their start. See https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro and [the Tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec: Slice types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

> The array underlying a slice may extend **past the end of the slice**. The *capacity* is a measure of that extent: **it is the sum of the length of the slice and the length of the array beyond the slice**; a slice of length up to that capacity can be created by [*slicing*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) a new one from the original slice. The capacity of a slice a can be discovered using the built-in function [`cap(a)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity).

Slices can be extended beyond the length (if the capacity allows), but not before the first element. The capacity therefore only includes elements that may be "claimed" after the last element with a slice expression.